# DLNA hardware player paired with router

Tags: linux, dlna, media-server

I have a powerfull router (ASUS RT-N66) with built-in DLNA server (minidlna) with no transcoding functionality. My Philips TV could play about 60-70% files directly from router's DLNA server.

So I would like to find a small and quiet solution for playing the rest of the files. I'm wonering if there is a hardware media server that will transcode files on the fly. I would prefer a small quiet box that will be installed near router, gets the infomation from it and gives additional DLNA output in my LAN, so that Philips could play everything.